# undefined variable food in cart food order

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a cart that display cart info of ordered food items.there is a button for checkout which prompts a modal body to enter delivery info

```
{!!Form::open(['action''OrdersController@store','method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
```

This is the store function

```
$order = new Order;
   $order->food=$food->food_item;
   $order->quantity=1;
   $order->price = $food->price;
   $order->restaurant = $food->restaurant_id;
   $order->delivery_address=$request->input('delivery_address');
   $order->user_name=$request->input('user_name');
   $order->phone_number=$request->input('phone_number');

   $order->save();
}
```

This is the cart session details

```
    "name" => $food->food_item,
    "quantity" => 1,
    "price" => $food->price,
    "restaurant" =>$food->restaurant_id,
```

This is the addToCart function
public function addToCart($id){
        $food = Food::find($id);

```
    if(!$food) {

        abort(404);

    }

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart = [
                $id => [
                    // "productId" => $food->id,
                    "name" => $food->food_item,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "price" => $food->price,
                    "restaurant" =>$food->restaurant_id,

                ]
        ];
```

Comment: Where is `$food` defined?

Comment: in the foodsController of which i've included the Food model in the orders controller since they have a relationship

Comment: If it isn't defined in the store method of OrdersController then you'll get an error. I don't see it in your code.

Comment: how will i define it? its the variable that carries the cart details

Comment: Just edit your question with the full store method. Including the declaration... If you have something like `public function store(Request $request) { $order = new Order; $order->food=$food->food_item;` Then `$food` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: updated my code @IGP

Comment: What about the store method?